# How do I link the Stack Exchange data together?

Tags: support, answers, data-dump

I was trying to link the Stack Exchange data together from the [archive.org data dump](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange) as my college database subject project, but I can't understand how to link the Post and its answer. I tried to link using postlinks relation, but it didn't work that way...

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the posts data set, there is a `ParentId` field. For answers, this is the `Id` of the "parent" question. Questions are `PostTypeId` = 1 and answers are `PostTypeId` = 2.